# Announcement is being interrupted by talkback focus

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, talkback

We have a footer button that when the user taps over it, the screen is being recomposed and then, an announcement should be read by talkback, like this:

```
 val currentView = LocalView.current

//And then, after recomposition
currentView.announceForAccessibility("This is a sample message for the announcement after recomposition)
```

The point here is that, after recomposition, a top bar element gains the focus and the announcement is interrupted.

Any idea of how can I solve this?